# How to add second array objects in first array object based on id value using angular6?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my code

```js
categories = [{"id":"101","name":"category1"},{"id":"102","name":"category2"},{"id":"103","name":"category3"},{"id":"104","name":"category4"}];

actions = [{"id":"201","name":"action1","category_id":"101"},{"id":"202","name":"action2","category_id":"101"},{"id":"203","name":"action3","category_id":"102"},{"id":"204","name":"action4","category_id":"104"}];
```

In the above `categories` array id value is existed in `actions` array. so i want to combine the two arrays into one array like the output as follows.

Output:-

```js
finalList = [{"id":"101","name":"category1","actions":[{"id":"201","name":"action1","category_id":"101"},{"id":"202","name":"action2","category_id":"101"}]},{"id":"102","name":"category2","actions":[{"id":"203","name":"action3","category_id":"102"}]},{"id":"103","name":"category3","actions":[]},{"id":"104","name":"category4","actions":[{"id":"204","name":"action4","category_id":"104"}]}]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each category find action elements and add then to category object

```
this.categories.forEach((element) => {
    element['actions'] = this.actions.filter((data) => data.category_id === element.id);
});
console.log(this.categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the map function along with the `filter`

```js
var categories = [{"id":"101","name":"category1"},{"id":"102","name":"category2"},{"id":"103","name":"category3"},{"id":"104","name":"category4"}];

var actions = [{"id":"201","name":"action1","category_id":"101"},{"id":"202","name":"action2","category_id":"101"},{"id":"203","name":"action3","category_id":"102"},{"id":"204","name":"action4","category_id":"104"}];

var result = categories.map((item) => {
  item.action = actions.filter( ac => item.id === ac. category_id)
  return item;
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Array.reduce()` to create a map of actions ,group by `category Id`. And than you can use `Array.map()` on the categories to get the desired result. The overall time complexity of this solution will be `O(n)`.

```js
let categories = [{"id":"101","name":"category1"},{"id":"102","name":"category2"},{"id":"103","name":"category3"},{"id":"104","name":"category4"}];

let actions = [{"id":"201","name":"action1","category_id":"101"},{"id":"202","name":"action2","category_id":"101"},{"id":"203","name":"action3","category_id":"102"},{"id":"204","name":"action4","category_id":"104"}];

let map = actions.reduce((a,curr)=>{
  (a[curr.category_id]  = a[curr.category_id] || []).push(curr);
  return a;
},{});

let result = categories.map((o)=>{
  o.actions = map[o.id] || [];
  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Use simple for loop along with filter 
categories = [{"id":"101","name":"category1"},{"id":"102","name":"category2"},{"id":"103","name":"category3"},{"id":"104","name":"category4"}];

actions = [{"id":"201","name":"action1","category_id":"101"},{"id":"202","name":"action2","category_id":"101"},{"id":"203","name":"action3","category_id":"102"},{"id":"204","name":"action4","category_id":"104"}];

    for(var i=0;i<categories.length;i++){
        categories[i]['actions'] = actions.filter((data) => data.category_id === categories[i].id);
    };
    console.log(categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using for loops working fine.

```js
for(var i=0;i<categories.length;i++)
{
   categories[i]["actions"]=[];
   for(var j=0;j<actions.length;j++)
   {
     if(categories[i].id==actions[j].category_id){
       categories[i]["actions"].push(actions[j]);
     }
   }
}
```

Any other approach without using for loops?